# How stop the login id from adding and removing other users and logins from the database?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse

I cannot stop the login id from dropping or modifying the other user from the database.

I have created one role using the code below:

```
CREATE ROLE super_users;  

GRANT Select, Alter, Update, Execute, Insert, Delete, Create View, Create Table 
ON database::[sampledb] TO super_users;

REVOKE CONTROL ON database::[sampledb] TO super_users;

--Created user for login
CREATE USER user_1 for login user_1;
  
--giving role to particular use
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'super_users', 'user_1 '
```

Despite doing all of this, the user of this login can delete or drop the other users and login?

Can anyone please help on how to prevent the login id's from doing the above or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: No, it can't. If the user is not the db_owner, it won't have the permission to drop the login. And only the server-level principal login (created by the provisioning process) or members of the loginmanager database role in the master database can create new logins.

Comment: If you create the user_1 on the User DB and give the 'super_users' role to user_1 . user_1 can drop users of this User DB.

Comment: I have not explicitly specified that it is db_owner. Is there any way to stop it?

Comment: I think we need to further restrict the permissions of the 'super_users' role.

Comment: Thanks man. Did it by this code deny ALTER ANY USER,ALTER ANY ROLE,CREATE ROLE

Comment: Yes, I've read some documentations to find the answer. So may I post it as answer?

Comment: Sure, Joseph. Also please if you can explain the use of the "Control" keyword then it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

As we know, we can use the following script to create a DB role and create corresponding permissions.

```sql
CREATE ROLE super_users;  

GRANT Select, Alter, Update, Execute, Insert, Delete, Create View, Create Table 
ON database::[sampledb] TO super_users;

--Created user for login
CREATE USER user_1 for login user_1;
  
--giving role to particular use
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'super_users', 'user_1 '
```

But after that we realized  `user_1` has the permission to drop other users of the `[sampledb]`. When we run `REVOKE CONTROL ON database::[sampledb] to super_users` but not work, `user_1` still has the permission . The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/revoke-database-principal-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#database-role-permissions)'s explanation of `REVOKE CONTROL` is very general. But it doesn't work for `CREATE,ALTER,Drop other DB Users`.

So we need to use the following script to further restrict the permissions of the 'super_users' role.

```
DENY ALTER ANY USER,ALTER ANY ROLE,CREATE ROLE to super_users
```

After that, 'user_1 ' of the 'super_users' can't `CREATE,ALTER,Drop other DB Users`

Comment: Hi @BrownBatman. I've updated my answer. But the official documentation's explanation of `REVOKE CONTROL` is general.